# How to retrieve data for ConfigurationManager.AppSettings from another source (not file)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, appsettings, configurationmanager

Can I retrieve data for ConfigurationManager.AppSettings from another source of data different from appsettings file? For example from Json Object.

Comment: No, but you can write an AppSettings class of your own which can get the data from any source.